# Firebase Import error.Issue in plugin_platform_interface.dart / Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/path_provider_platform_interface.dart:10:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin_platform_interface-1.0.3/lib/plugin_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/path_provider_platform_interface.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin_platform_interface-1.0.3/lib/plugin_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_platform_interface-1.1.1/lib/src/platform_interface/image_picker_platform.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin_platform_interface-1.0.3/lib/plugin_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/path_provider_platform_interface.dart:22:45: Error: Type 'PlatformInterface' not found.
abstract class PathProviderPlatform extends PlatformInterface {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_platform_interface-1.1.1/lib/src/platform_interface/image_picker_platform.dart:20:44: Error: Type 'PlatformInterface' not found.
abstract class ImagePickerPlatform extends PlatformInterface {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/path_provider_platform_interface.dart:24:34: Error: No named parameter with the name 'token'.
PathProviderPlatform() : super(token: _token);
^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/path_provider_platform_interface.dart:38:5: Error: Getter not found: 'PlatformInterface'.
PlatformInterface.verifyToken(instance, _token);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_platform_interface-1.1.1/lib/src/platform_interface/image_picker_platform.dart:22:33: Error: No named parameter with the name 'token'.
ImagePickerPlatform() : super(token: _token);
^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_platform_interface-1.1.1/lib/src/platform_interface/image_picker_platform.dart:38:5: Error: Getter not found: 'PlatformInterface'.
PlatformInterface.verifyToken(instance, _token);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finishe

Comment: Adding context about your question, rather than just the error message, is very helpful for people answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution for a long time and the solution wasn't in the Stack overflow. Finally I resolved this error by running-

1)flutter pub cache repair
2)flutter clean
3)flutter run

try this